# Should I use curly brackets {} or square brackets [] in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have an array using an increasing index:

```
var idx = 1;
var a = [];
a[idx++] = "apple";
a[idx++] = "orange";
...
console.log(a[2]);
```

And only accessing it by `[]`, not using array specific functions, like `length`, `indexOf`, ...

Apparently following is also working in this case:

```
var a = {};
```

So, which one should I prefer in such case? For example any performance difference between them?

Comment: Depends on the data you have and what you want to do with it. If you just have a "list" of things, use an array. Arrays are probably also optimized by the engine.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, that's what I'd like to know. Don't know why so many downvotes...

Comment: @FelixKling though from memory, most JS implementations also optimise for array-like objects, so they actually have similar performance. Not sure whether this would apply in this instance though, as the first element is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @Deqing: Probably because the question "*What does this notation mean?*" lacks research effort, you could have found out about object/array literals in every basic tutorial (or by searching StackOverflow). Ask a question "*Should I use an array or an object for task XY?*"

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: that could very well be! I ran a couple of tests recently and noticed that there are differences in chrome at least when dealing with large arrays and objects, with and with consecutive keys. But it didn't make a difference in node at all. I just imagined that chrome can't do its hidden class thing with objects like this one. I'm not very familiar with optimizations, so I should probably not even have mentioned it. But it's too late now :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ ] denotes an array. Arrays only hold values:

```
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As @Qantas pointed out, array can hold more than just values.  An array can even contain another array and/or object:

```
var a2 = [1, 2, ["apple", "orange"], {one: "grape", two: "banana"}];
```

{ } denotes an object.  Objects have key-value pairs like

```
var a3 = {one: 1, two: 2}
```

In your case, it's really a matter of how you would like to be able to access the data.  If you are only interested in knowing "apple", "pear", etc.  Go ahead and use an array.  You can access it via it's index

```
a1[0]; // outputs 1
a1[1]; // outputs 2
```

or you can iterate over it with a loop.  If you use the curly braces, (given the example I gave) you could access it with

```
a3.one; // outputs 1
a3["two"]; // outputs 2
```

It's really up to you on how it would best fit your needs in this case.  For a more extensive discussion see this [article](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html).

Comment: Arrays in JavaScript build on objects and can also store key-value pairs like objects, so this doesn't really answer the question. From what I understand, the OP is asking whether it's a good idea to use an object like an array or not.

Comment: Ok, maybe I shouldn't say it is an `array`. Just like to know if it makes any difference by using `{}` in my case.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is using square brackets will create an Array object while using curly brackets creates a plain object. For example:

```
a = [];
a[1] = 'a';

b = {};
b[1] = 'b';

a.length; // returns 2
b.length; // is undefined

a.push('z'); // add 'z' to the end of a
b.push('z'); // generates an error - undefined is not a function
             // because plain objects don't have a push method
```

Read the MDN documentation on Array objects to know more about arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array